# How can I select all in a Google doc with an iPad?

Tags: ipad, copy-paste, google-docs

I created a new Google doc on my iPad2. When I **select all** to copy the whole contents, it only selects the current line.

Is there a known workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the google docs into desktop mode. Click the Desktop link  at the bottom of the page.

> View in: Mobile | Desktop

Then select edit menu in Google docs then "Select all"

Comment: Thx. I tried this but 1. I had to convert the docs to the new format, which Google is going to make obligatory anyway :( and 2. I got an infinite (presumably) series of error pop ups from Google! This happens even with a new doc!